# PDF file not showing dynamic information

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am using mpdf, when the output comes out it is showing me only the $body information. Does anyone know why it is not showing the $maand? Is this the right way to do it? Do I need to change the position of the $maand? What can I do to get this to work? And after the information of $body it is also not showing the

Periode

. How can I fix that?
Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("");
    //get data
    $query= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * From Info");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL>Factuurdatum:<?php echo date('d-m-Y');?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL>Klantnummer:<?php echo $row['id']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL>Vervaldatum:<?php echo date("d-m-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+14, date("Y")));?></span></p>

    <?php
    $body= ob_get_clean();
    $body = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $body);
    require ("mpdf/vendor/autoload.php");
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)">
<style>
<!--
 /* Font Definitions */
 @font-face
    {font-family:"Cambria Math";
    panose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}
@font-face
    {font-family:Verdana;
    panose-1:2 11 6 4 3 5 4 4 2 4;}
 /* Style Definitions */
 p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:9.0pt;
    font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;}
p.MsoHeader, li.MsoHeader, div.MsoHeader
    {margin:0in;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:9.0pt;
    font-family:"Verdana",sans-serif;}
 /* Page Definitions */
 @page WordSection1
    {size:595.3pt 841.9pt;
    margin:21.7pt 70.9pt 70.9pt 70.9pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body lang=EN-GB>
<div class=WordSection1>
<p class=MsoNormal style=\'margin-left:31.5pt\'><span lang=NL></span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal style=\'margin-left:31.5pt\'><span lang=NL><a name=Text6></a></span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal style=\'margin-left:31.5pt\'><span lang=NL>&nbsp;</span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal style=\'margin-left:31.5pt\'><span lang=EN-US></span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal style=\'margin-left:31.5pt\'><span lang=EN-US>&nbsp;</span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal style=\'margin-left:31.5pt\'><span lang=EN-US>&nbsp;</span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL>&nbsp;</span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal align=right style=\'text-align:right\'><span lang=NL>&nbsp;</span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal align=right style=\'text-align:right\'><span lang=NL>T.a.v. crediteurenadministratie</span><span
lang=NL> </span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal align=right style=\'margin-left:31.5pt;text-align:right\'><span
lang=NL>&nbsp;</span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal align=right style=\'margin-left:31.5pt;text-align:right\'><span
lang=NL>&nbsp;</span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal align=right style=\'margin-left:31.5pt;text-align:right\'><span
lang=NL></span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal style=\'margin-left:31.5pt\'><b><span lang=NL>&nbsp;</span></b></p>
<p class=MsoNormal><b><u><span lang=NL style=\'font-size:14.0pt\'>FACTUUR</span></u></b></p>
<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL>&nbsp;</span></p>
<p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL>&nbsp;</span></p>');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($body);
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<p class=MsoNormal><b><span lang=NL>&nbsp;</span></b></p>
<p class=MsoNormal><b><span lang=NL>&nbsp;</span></b></p>
<p class=MsoNormal><b><span lang=NL>&nbsp;</span></b></p>
<p class=MsoNormal><b><span lang=NL>&nbsp;</span></b></p>
<table class=MsoNormalTable border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0
 style=\'border-collapse:collapse;border:none\'>
 <tr style=\'height:27.65pt\'>
  <td width=215 valign=top style=\'width:161.4pt;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  border-left:none;border-bottom:solid windowtext 1.0pt;border-right:none;
  padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:27.65pt\'>
  <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL>Periode</span></p>');
ob_start();
?>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row ['Januari']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Februari']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Maart']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['April']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Mei']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Juni']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Juli']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Augustus']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['September']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Oktober']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['November']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['December']?></span></p>
<?php
$maand = ob_get_clean();
$maand = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $maand);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($maand);
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the options for [WriteHTML](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/writehtml.html#examples), it looks like if you intend to call it multiple times then you need tell it not to close the document.

> **$initialise** Set true or false to determine whether to initialise all
>   buffers, starting all HTML elements from new. See example #2 for use.
>   You must start with a WriteHTML() that calls $initialise = true.
>
> Default: true
>
> **$close** Set true or false to specify whether all HTML elements are
>   closed, and buffers cleared. See example #2 for use. You must end with
>   a WriteHTML() that calls $close = true.
>
> Default: true

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
    //get data
    $query= mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * From Info");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL>Factuurdatum:<?php echo date('d-m-Y');?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL>Klantnummer:<?php echo $row['id']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL>Vervaldatum:<?php echo date("d-m-Y", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m"), date("d")+14, date("Y")));?></span></p>

    <?php
    $body= ob_get_clean();
    $body = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $body);
    require ("mpdf/vendor/autoload.php");
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->WriteHTML($body, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY, true, false);
ob_start();
?>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Januari']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Februari']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Maart']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['April']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Mei']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Juni']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Juli']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Augustus']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['September']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['Oktober']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['November']?></span></p>
    <p class=MsoNormal><span lang=NL><?php echo $row['December']?></span></p>
<?php
$maand = ob_get_clean();
$maand = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $maand);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($maand, \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY, false, true);
$mpdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: I have tried it, and it it still not showing me the $maand.

Comment: I tried it and it works on mine, latest version (no db obv just strings), have you checked `$maand` is being captured? if all fails just concatenate the string and do it in one shot, the ob_* stuff needs abstracting anyway, $mpdf->WriteHTML(render('report', [.data.])) is much nicer ;p

Comment: What do I exactly need to put in the [.data.]?

Comment: Or is there an easier way to echo out the information of sql to the pdf?

Comment: Could you check my question again I have changed it on how it is now.

Comment: same, you need to use WriteHTML correctly your still not doing it with 2,3 and 4th params.

Comment: the fonts wont work, and dont think you include the outer HTML wrap, that's what the WriteHTML params are for.

Comment: thanks it is working now, but I only have one problem, I have used a converter from pdf to html, and when I past this code it is not exactly like the pdf file when I want to use dynamic information. Do you maybe have a solution to this?

Comment: np, im a fan of building a webpage as a normal page/endpoint to the app maybe a bit protected with a query param or cookie etc and then just using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to render that page into a pdf `$pdf->addPage('http://www.example.com/pdfs/report/foo?key=123');`, or do it clientside with jsPDF, its easier than faffing with bundling assets and fonts

Comment: Thanks, and how can I go from pdf to html?

Comment: with great difficulty and headaches ;p na https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poppler_(software)#poppler-utils -> pdftohtml use a wrapper in PHP https://github.com/mgufrone/pdf-to-html

Comment: haha thanks, sorry for all my questions. I am a student and my teacher is not replying to my mails. Do you maybe have an email where I could ask you something if I have trouble.